# Rails 2.3.14 localization for yes/no

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have YAML like so, in /config/locales/defaults/en.yml:

```
en:
  no_results_found: None Found
  yes: Yes
  no: No
  approve: Approve
```

And get these results in rails console:

```
>> helper.t(:no_results_found)
=> "None Found"
>> helper.t(:yes)
=> "<span class=\"translation_missing\">en, yes</span>"
>> helper.t(:no)
=> "<span class=\"translation_missing\">en, no</span>"
>> helper.t(:approve)
=> "Approve"
```

I've tried renaming yes/no to yes_text, and no_text, and get weirder results:

```
>> helper.t(:yes_text)
=> true
>> helper.t(:no_text)
=> false
```

How can I output (in English) yes or no? Keep in mind I define in yaml so I can provide versions in other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
en:
 no_results_found: "None Found"
 result_yes: "Yes"
 result_no: "No"
 approve: "Approve"
```

Add some prefix with yes: or no: translation variable as it is default in i18n.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
en:
  'yes': Yes
  'no': No
```

Comment: But how is that translated to Russian or Chinese?